# Azure worker instances with different configurations

Tags: azure, scaling

I have next situation:

1) N workers, all workers do same things

2) Each worker have persistant socket connection to third party service, so one connection should be served by one instance of worker

My question: how to implement workers to pickup one connection, and let others workers instnaces to know that connection to third party sertvice already established?

Currently i implemented this by queue, so another worker(lets say scaling worker) place message into queue, and this messages fetched one by one by workers.

Does there any better solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement inter-role communication via WCF and endpoints or the Azure AppFabric messaging bus.  Check out a tutorial on how to do this here, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee706736.aspx.

Answer (score 0):

One technique is to obtain a lease on a blob, since only one writer can have the lease at any given time. The pattern would be something like:

- Attempt to obtain lease
- If successful, open connection
- If unsuccessful, sleep for some period of time and try again

This pattern is also used when, say, creating a database server which opens data files on an Azure Drive, and running in two instances (one instance obtains the lease and runs the server; the other fails to obtain the lease and periodically retries).

Comment: This is very similar to my current realization, but lease issued by one of the workers(scaling) for other workers. I think brocker will be better solution, but anyway thank you